# Proving Quantifier statements are true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logic, quantifiers

I have a question of the likes of:
Show that:

$\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \forall n \in [m,+\infty), 10n^2 +100/n > 0$.

I'm not sure exactly where to and how to start this question.  I have a variety of properties in front of me, but I'm not sure how I would go about using them. I know at first I should state "let n be an integer", but then I'm completely lost.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve for $n$ in the inequality? You're looking for a positive $m$ such that any number that is at least as big as $m$ makes the inequality true.

Comment: "There exists $m$..." : clearly, $m=1$ satisfies. Done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Order matter here, so your first thoughts are on the correct path.

The answer is m=1.

Now this is how you prove it. Note that in the inequality n cannot equal 0 because 100/0 is not allowed. so since n cannot equal 0, and m is in the Z+ set , setting m=1 will make the statement true for any value of Y.

Make sense? hope it helps